# Perl rounding bug for printf/sprintf

Tags: perl, printf, rounding-error

Can anyone explain how this this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
my $amount = 74.32 * 100.00;

printf "Unformatted Amount:${amount}:\n";
printf " Formatted Amount:%.11d:\n", $amount;
```

Outputs this:

```
$ ./test.pl
Unformatted Amount:7432:
  Formatted Amount:00000007431:
```

At the moment I've stopped using printf and sprintf as I don't trust them. So I'm doing this instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
my $amount = 74.32 * 100.00;

$formatted_amount = "00000000000" . $amount;
$formatted_amount = substr($formated_amount,length($formatted_amount)-11,11);

printf "Unformatted Amount:${amount}:\n";
printf "  Formatted Amount:${formatted_amount}:\n";
```

which works but curious as to why I need to do this.

I understand how binary numbers cannot exactly represent all base 10 numbers, and have read this Stack Overflow entry: [How to eliminate Perl rounding errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232921/how-to-eliminate-perl-rounding-errors), but I honestly did not expect to see a problem with such a seemingly simple example.

Also the value of $amount **is** correct. It's just printf is not printing it correctly!

Any ideas?

Comment: Wierd. Especially as `%.11f` gives the correct answer. Apparently the conversion to integer gets butchered. Thus as a workaround for integers, `%11.0f` appears to work.

Comment: @DeVadder: As I said, Perl *always* truncates floats to convert them to integers. They had to choose one way to do it, and truncation is the fastest. If you want anything else you can easily code it.

Comment: @Borodin: Yep, i got it, thanks. I would just have expected that converting floats to ints and to any precision would work equal. Either both truncate or both round. Basically i would always have assumed `%d` to be the same as `%.0f` by default. And if truncation was the way to go, i would have expected `%.5f` to have nines after the decimal point by default.

Comment: @DeVadder: I'm not clear what you mean by your last sentence. It is only the conversion from floating point to integer that truncates. As I said, it's far faster than any sort of rounding, and is what C and all the other languages I know do. A format specifier of `%.5f` does *no* conversion because it expects a floating point value. It will round that value at the fifth decimal place, so 0.123456 would be formatted as `0.12346`, which 0.654321 would apear as `0.65432`. Does that help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `printf` should give up on *you*!

What do you expect a specifier of `%.11d` to do?

The value *after* the decimal point is a *precision*, and [`perldoc -f sprintf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) says this

> For integer conversions, specifying a precision implies that
>                   the output of the number itself should be zero-padded to
>                   this width, where the 0 flag is ignored

If you want a *minimum width* of 11 characters than just omit the decimal point - `%11d` will give you what you want.

Perl converts floating point numbers to integers by *truncating* them, and as `74.32 * 100.0` is *slightly less* than 7432, `int(74.32 * 100.0)` is 7431. If you want your floating point value rounded to the nearest integer then use the `f` format specifier with a zero precision, like `%11.0f`.

To zero-pad a field, take a look at the *flags* section of the above document. The flag character appears before the width specifier: `0 use zeros, not spaces, to right-justify`.

Check this program

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $amount = 74.32 * 100.00;

printf "Unformatted Amount:    ${amount}\n";
printf "Truncated Amount:      %d\n", $amount;
printf "High-precision Amount: %20.16f\n", $amount;
printf "Rounded Amount:        %.0f\n", $amount;
printf "Padded Amount:         %011.0f\n", $amount;
```

**output**

```
Unformatted Amount:    7432
Truncated Amount:      7431
High-precision Amount: 7431.9999999999991000
Formatted Amount:      7432
Padded Amount:         00000007432
```

Comment: I am pretty sure his issue are not the zeros but the fact that printf gives him 7431 instead of 7432. Whether or not there is a decimal point.

Comment: @DeVadder: Yes, I've just addressed that.

Comment: Yeah I want 0 padded decimal amount and my problem is the change from 7432 to 7431.I can't use %11d or %11.0f as it doesn't zero pad. Interestingly %011s does work.

Comment: And so does %011.0f. OK starting to understand a little more and thanks for the information on truncating. Guess I shouldn't assume a floating point number is the same as a decimal. Will leave this open for a little longer in case anyone has anything further to add but this looks like the answer I'll accept.

Comment: @BazzaDP: As DeVadder says, and as I've updated my answer to show, `%011.0f` is the correct format specifier for  rounding a floating point and zero-padding to 11 digits.

Comment: @BazzaDP: You can *never* rely on the result of a floating point *calculation* to be an exact integer, as *most* fractional values can't be represented accurately in a finite number of bits. 74.32 is one of those values.

Comment: Agree with you somewhat, just confused me that printing the floating point number printed 7432 (so calculation looked to be right), but printing the decimal number printed 7431. So perl is interpreting float->string "correctly" but not float->decimal->string due to the truncation point you noted.

Comment: @BazzaDP: Yes. A `%d` specifier converts the parameter to an integer with `int()`, just as a `%s` specifier converts it to a string with `""`.